# How to add native modules in React Native 0.60+?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying to understand the difference between the autolinking that exists in React Native 0.60+ and the automatic / manual linking we have in previous React Native versions.
When I add [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) with `npm i react-native-gesture-handler`, no lines are added to my Podfile. So when I do `pod install`, I assume the Gesture Handler module isn't linked. However, if I link it manually as I did with previous React Native versions, by dragging the `.xcodeproj` files into Libraries etc, it throws an error and tells me to unlink it.

**What I Want To Know:**

Am I right that what autolinking does is adds a line for the given module to your Podfile, which then gets linked when you `pod install`? If so, why might it be that when I did `npm i react-native-gesture-handler` nothing was added to my Podfile? And given that nothing was added and linking the module manually throws an error, how should I link the module?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new project and react-native version >=60 , this line is automatically added in pod file ([official site](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md))

```
# example/ios/Podfile
require_relative '../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

This is path of script , so when you run "pod install" , it will check all libraries and install all pods files required

**So when you add new library , no lines are added to my Podfile but you have to run "pod install" so that script file can run and install new pod files .**

Please do not use manual linking as described in [official site](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)

> This means that all libraries need to ship a Podspec either in the
>   root of their folder or where the Xcode project is. Podspec references
>   the native code that your library depends on.
>
> The implementation ensures that a library is imported only once. If
>   you need to have a custom pod directive then include it above the
>   use_native_modules! function.

**You have to do 2 steps**

1 : Add library **"yarn add react-native-gesture-handler"**

2 : cd ios && pod install

Comment: I was reeling with this problem a little too long. It happened because react-native upgrade did not automatically add this to the Pods file.

Just to add to the answer, you also need to add

```
use_native_modules!
```

in the Pod file.

Comment: This is happening when the react root directory having the iOS directory inside. but when i try to have the iOS directory outside the react root native modules are not working. Any idea???